# A short story about fast-evolving intelligent creatures created in a lab

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in some short-stories collection I borrowed from a library many years ago. Maybe it was Hugo or Nebula award winner or runner-up (Yes, I tried to look at the titles of Hugo and Nebula winners and runners up - but to no avail).

It's about a scientist who creates (or modify) a 'race' of small creatures with very short life-spans. With the passing of time (due to the different evolutionary timescale), the race evolves and becomes technologically advanced. I believe the name of this race was "Noetherics" or something like that. The scientist is perceived as a god and - IIRC - this was due to the fact that he instilled the idea by means of a reward/punishment mechanism during the early stages of evolution.
What I remember is that toward the end of the story...

SPOILER ALERT

> ! the scientist is in danger because his fellow humans think he has too much power and so, very graciously, they decided to nuke the little island where he lives and has his lab. He can only transmit a short message to the creatures: "Gimme shelter!" when he believes it's already too late and...
>   ... the creatures build a machine that projects a force field (a dome?) all around the island, making it impermeable to missile attack.

Does all this ring a bell?

Comment: Never mind, I found it in the related column: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72627/short-story-identification-scientist-dome?rq=1 . It's "Microcosmic God" by Theodore Sturgeon. You guys are even better than I had thought!!!

Comment: :) Nevertheless, that was a nicely detailed question.

Comment: Thanks, I am leaving it because it might help someone else finding this beautiful story. I did try to search SFFSE before asking, but I did not use the magic word "dome". Perhaps another duplicate will be of help.

Comment: That's how the system works. :)